# Split first <br> from sentence using vb

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, split

I have the one sentence `Eric Corni<br>chargé de clientèle<br>Tél: 09 99 99 99 99 72<br> atricard@adiscos.com` I want to get only `chargé de clientèle<br>Tél: 09 99 99 99 99 72<br> atricard@adiscos.com`

I have the code as below:

```
strText = Replace(strText, "_com_position_", Right(com_signature,InStrRev(com_signature, ">", len(com_signature))+3))
```

And `_com_position_ = "Eric Corni<br>chargé de clientèle<br>Tél: 09 99 99 99 99 72<br> atricard@adiscos.com"` but it displays wrong with what I need.it displays like this: `gé de clientèle<br>Tél: 09 99 99 99 99 72<br> atricard@adiscos.com`

Do you have any solution, please help me to fix it, Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you actually using? VB, VB.net or VBScript? They are three different languages, despite sharing some similarities.

Answer (score 0):

Use instr function() .. and known that length of `<br>` is 4 then

```
Dim strText As String = "Eric Corni<br>chargé de clientèle<br>Tél: 09 99 99 99 99 72<br>    atricard@adiscos.com"

strText = Mid(strText,InStr(strText, "<br>") + 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strText = strText.SubString(strText.IndexOf("<br>") + 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (using [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript)) would be to remove the first part of the string with a regular expression:

```
strText = "Eric Corni<br>chargé de ..."

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^.*?<br>"
re.IgnoreCase = True

WScript.Echo re.Replace(strText, "")
```